# Running Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 8 at the same time

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-8

I'm inspired by the capability of the upcoming Asus Transformer Trio to switch between Android and Windows at the push of a button. As I understand it, this is because each OS is stored on its own dedicated drive.

My question is this: if I were to set up a desktop with 2x hard drives, one for Ubuntu and the other for Windows, would it be possible to set this up in a way that I could switch between the two without ever having to log out? I see plenty of posts on here stating that I can set it up so I can choose between either OS or hard drive at the boot screen, but I'm interested in being able to switch with a simple keyboard shortcut, not unlike switching between programs using ALT+tab. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible with actual installations.  Virtual machines, maybe, but not actual on-the-hard-drives-directly installations.

Comment: Yeah... what to do with all the states of the hardware? You effectively have to suspend-to-disk and resume every time. That is very time consuming.

Comment: Asus Trio TX201 is actually 2 computers that can run at same time - one android and other is a 'normal' PC. I can boot windows but I now run Ubuntu 14.10. My main problem is with screen brightness contol. Otherwise is works well.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you cannot run two operating systems at the same time, because you have no way to boot both of them simaltaneously, even if you did overcome that hiccup they would both be fighting to control your hardware. I'm not saying it isn't possible, I'm just saying until windows and ubuntu are written to support such a feature (which is unlikely) you can't do it. That said, the technology already sort of exists, windows 8 has a new feature called fast-boot which means that every computer in the world running windows 8 never turns off completely, unless the administrator disables fast-boot, windows 8 is setup to maintain partial hardware control even when you boot into another operating system like ubuntu, which is known to cause some issues.

You might consider running windows and ubuntu in Virtual machines? That way can switch between them anytime and run them at the same time. I recommend VMware Player because it has the best graphics card emulation out of all the products I've tried, however if you want more features, then try virtual box. If you aren't familair with virtual machines, you can think of them as a program you install that pretends to be a computer, you can install operating systems into it attach virtual and real hardware to it (limitations apply), and use it like a real computer.

You could also try coLinux, or andlinux which are modified versions of linux designed to run within windows, however they only support 32bit windows, and there are limitations to what you can do, also the linux softare will not have access to your graphics capabilities, and some other hardware.

sincerely, tapthoseshoesandwish